# Add Repeater items to Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, repeater

I have a Repeater which contains Eval commands and a Button (Which I can't access) I would like to access this button and when clicked insert one of the Eval commands (Eg. Car Model) into a listbox I have on the same page.

```
<asp:Button ID="modelButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Model") %>' Text='<%# "Add Model to List:" + Eval("Model") %>' runat="server" />  


<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataMember="DefaultView" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>     
            <p><img src="carImages/<%#Eval("Artwork")%>" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">    
            <h4><%# Eval("Make")%> (<%# Eval("Year") %>)</h4>
            <p><%# Eval("Model")%></p>
            <p><%# Eval("Colour")%></p>
            <p><%# Eval("Type")%></p>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="modelButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Model") %>' Text='<%# "Add Model to List:" + Eval("Model") %>' runat="server" />  
            </div>
          </a>
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't access the button?

Comment: Because it's inside the Repeater I'm unable to access it. I'm not sure how to get access to it.

Comment: Are you binding the repeater and are you able to click the button itself?

Comment: The Repeater is bound to an AccessDataSource. I am able to click the button yes, but not able to create a button_click event handler as its inside the Repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your oncommand argument to the repeated button

```
<asp:Button ID="modelButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Model") %>' OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" Text='<%# "Add Model to List:" + Eval("Model") %>' runat="server" />
```

you can grab the eval in the behind code

```
void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e){
    var command = e.CommandArgument;
    // Do whatever with it here
}
```

That will get the evaluated model

Comment: It's now showing this Error:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: What is being passed through the eval?

Comment: Just Strings, like above ("Model") , ("Year"), ("Make") etc. The Repeater is connected to an AccessDataSource which has a SelectCommand ="SELECT * FROM [Cars]

Comment: Check this out: http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2009/12/how-to-use-clientscriptmanager-registerforeventvalidation-method/

Apply that to your button on load of the button.